# Convert JSON from MySQL to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

So i have this JSON in my MySQL Database

```
{
    "11011001": {
        "id": 11011001,
        "name": "Test",
        "price": 4,
        "inCart": 7
    }
}
```

Now i want to work with this data in PHP.
I got the JSON by doing this in PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT article FROM test WHERE id = '$id'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $aricle = $row["article"];
    } else {
        echo "Something went wrong";
    }
```

After that i did this which resulted in getting a JSON Array:

```
$tarray = json_decode($article, TRUE);
```

What can i do now to get the values from the JSON?
For example i want the value of the price in a variable called $price.

Comment: You meant article not aricle didn't you?

Comment: What is this doing `$aricle = $["article"];`? I yhink it should be `$aricle = $row["article"];` and then put it into json decode

Comment: yes i forgot to adjust it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$price = $tarray[11011001]['price'];
```

Or you can loop through the results if you have many *articles*

```
$tarray = json_decode($json,true);
        foreach ($tarray as $index => $item)
        {
            $price[] =  $item['price'];
        }
        var_dump($price);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you might have a collection of items, you can map the ids to prices with array_column.

```
<?php

$json =<<<JSON
{
    "11011001": {
        "id": 11011001,
        "name": "Test",
        "price": 4,
        "inCart": 7
    }
}
JSON;

$items = json_decode($json, TRUE);

$ids_prices = array_column($items, 'price', 'id');

var_export($ids_prices);
```

Output:

```
array (
    11011001 => 4,
)
```

Only one item, but you don't know the key up front?

```
if(count($items) === 1) {
    $item  = array_pop($items);
    $price = $item['price'];
}
echo $price;
```

Output:

```
4
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have a sql injection, you must create a prepared query if you have data from users.

```
$sql = "SELECT article FROM test WHERE id = :id";
$query = $con->prepare($sql);
$query->bindValue(":id", $id);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetch();
if ($result) {
    // $article will be stdClass if json correct
    $article = json_decode($result['article']);
    $price = $article->price;
    // or $article = json_decode($result['article'], true);
    // $price = $article['price'];
    
}
```

Just an example